# How to weight all vertices for a selected bone?

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-paint, vertex-weights

I have a mesh that I tried auto painting the weights on. It didn't turn out as expected see this screen shot:

[image]

I'd like to set the weight on all vertices for that bone to 0

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52613/assigning-vertex-groups-to-bones-precisely/52615

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Delete the vertex group, select the bone again, and Paint.
Blender will  create a new Empty vertex group for you.**

[image]

Vertex group Bone.001 is on the right side of image.  It is deleted on the left side.

[image]

By continuing to paint Blender created a new vertex group.