# How to fully weight a mesh to a bone?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, vertex-weights

I have a mesh cut up into chunks that is a 1x1 match with bones. e.g. shoulderMesh -> shoulderBone. FootMesh -> FootBone. I want the meshes to be full strength painted to the bones.

Can I do this without manual vertex painting the meshes?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52613/assigning-vertex-groups-to-bones-precisely/52615

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can select <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode*, select one vertex of the shoulderMesh, FootMesh, etc. chunk, and key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>. If the chunks really are separate, this should select only one chunk. If they are not truly separate, <kbd>B</kbd>ox or otherwise select the chunk.

With the chunk selected, go to the *Properties panel > Object Data tab > Vertex Groups panel*. Find the corresponding *Vertex Group* (should be named after your bone), make sure the *Weight:* value is set to 1, and click *Assign*.

*One Vertex Selected:*

[image]

*Ctrl + L keyed to select entire chunk:*

[image]

*Vertex Groups panel. Assign button visible while still in Edit Mode. Weight at 1 guarantees maximum weight assigned:*

[image]